# How to serve a text/css file from akka-backend?

Tags: css, akka

this is probably an easy question, but I wonder how to serve a style sheet correctly from an akka-back end. I have this link tag in my index.html file, but I cant see that ContentTypes has a `text/css` attribute. So either there has to be an equivalent or content type is specified differently for text/css. I have tried to send it as plain text, but style is gone on the front end.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css">

val route = get {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      complete(
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, Source.fromFile(index).mkString))
      )
    } ~ path("scripts") {
      complete(
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, Source.fromFile(javascript).mkString))
      )
    } ~ path("css") {
      complete(
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, Source.fromFile(css).mkString))
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: ContentType(MediaTypes.`text/css`,HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`) ?

Comment: wow. Thank you Victor:) That did the trick..